# Detect that a host is reachable via a jump host

Tags: networking, macos, ssh, proxy, ssh-tunnel

I have setup a tunnel on my mac(Mojave) through a jump host as such :

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand='ssh -W %h:%p bastion' -i my-emr.pem -ND 8888 hadoop@ip-my.ec2.internal
```

bastion is a host I have defined in my `~/.ssh/config`

This way I can access `ip-my.ec2.internal` etc. via a SOCKS5 proxy. I want to test whether this host is accessible via SOCKS5 proxy.

Is there a command I can use?

I can test if the bastion host is accessible using a command like this:

```
nc -G 2 -z my-bastion.com 22
```

Can I can extend the above command to test if the end host which is `ip-my.ec2.internal`?